# Computer Blocking CORS OPTIONS Request

Tags: http, networking, cors

This is driving me crazy! I'm trying to work with Amazon S3 CORS requests and they are not working on my computer. It seems that my computer is blocking or ignoring the OPTIONS request. If I run a CURL command from my terminal:

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS http://testing.bennadel.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```

... I get:

*curl: (52) Empty reply from server*

However, if I run the *same* request on a different computer (AirBook) on the *same* router, I get the expected response (in XML format):

*Insufficient information. Origin request header needed.*

I've tried flushing my dsn cache (via dscacheutil). I've tried changing my DNS to use Google's public DNS. I've tried restarting my computer. No luck! This computer keeps blocking the OPTIONS request and every other computer that I try allows it.

Suggestions? This computer (iMac) is connecting to my router over WiFi; but, so does the AirBook, which makes successful OPTIONS requests.

Also note, non-OPTIONS requests to the same URL work fine (ie, GET).

Comment: Firewall/proxy settings? Check your logs (Console.app) for firewall messages. Try a packet capture (tcpdump or Wireshark) to see what (if anything) is actually going out over the wire (and where that empty response is coming from).

Comment: Good thinking on the Console.app (I'm not used to debugging things at this level). It looks like anytime I try to do the OPTIONS HTTP request, this shows up in the console:  
  
11/22/13 10:18:17.967 AM acwebsecagent[294]: Connection : Auth key is not provided or is invalid, applying connection failure policy. CMode : 0 TMode : 0

Comment: Some Googling says this error may be related to "Cisco AnyConnect" which I do have installed (for a VPN requirement). From Apple Support: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3507331

Comment: Uninstalling "Cisco AnyConnect" helped solve the problem for me! Note that you had uninstall it completely. Just disabling it didn't work.

Comment: A few coworkers of mine ran into this issue and it was also the Cisco AnyConnect issue; @user3021922 do you mind answering your own question with that and marking it as the correct answer?  I almost didn't see these comments.

Answer (score 8):

More specifically, the problem seems to be in the Web Security module of AnyConnect. I was able to fix the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling AnyConnect with the Web Security option unchecked; or, just by running the websecurity_uninstall.sh script.  (This was with AnyConnect 3.1.04074.)

Thanks to the @user3021922 and others for identifying the issue - this was driving me crazy too.

Comment: Had the same problem, running `websecurity_uninstall.sh` fixed it (it's in `/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/websecurity_uninstall.sh`, at least on my OS X 10.10).

Comment: Used the GUI uninstall but worked for me too. Actually, any request worked for me (GET/POST/whatever), up until I tried file uploads, that gets completely blocked by this module on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Web Security module of Cisco AnyConnect. In our case, we cannot uninstall AnyConnect or make any changes to it (large corporate setting where the change would be really expensive/time consuming). Fortunately, there seem to be two solutions that do work.

1. Cisco only blocks ports `80` and `8080` (other ports seem fine).
2. Cisco allows secure `https` requests.

So, if you have control over the server, either put it on a different port or use https and your users will be alright.